# Implementing a delayed execution task with cancellation

Tags: .net, wpf, asynchronous, cancellation

I have a situation where I want to allow a user to type into a WPF TextBox, on each keystroke I call OnPropertyChanged and push to my binding source (using SourceUpdatedTrigger=PropertyChanged) I want there to be a short delay before attempting to process the data (say... 1 second)  Think of this like a spell check system where it waits for the user to stop typing before telling them they can't spell.

My issue is:

```
 await TaskEx.Delay(1000, cts.Token);
 await TaskEx.RunEx(PollAsync, cts.Token);
```

works fine until you actually cancel, but then the cancelation token source is permanantly in the "cancelation requested" state, and I have to reinstanciate the CTS... this seems... fundamentally wrong...  Is there a better way to "reset" the CTS, yet still notify existing tokens that they should cancel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a `CancellationTokenSource` can only be cancelled once - as you say, you need to create a new one after you've cancelled it, for further tasks.

Comment: is there a better "best practice" for delayed start processing like this?

Comment: @Firoso: Not that I'm aware of. I'm not sure that cancelling the task is the best approach here - possibly just don't bother processing it when it occurs if there's been another keystroke before then... keep a sort of "version counter" or something similar? Not sure.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi. Would you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082827/error-the-operation-was-canceled) please? Thanks in advance