# Error: The operation was canceled

Tags: c#-4.0, asynchronous, async-await, cancellation, cancellationtokensource

I'm using this code snippet to do an async query with a cancellation token:

```
var _client = new HttpClient( /* some setthngs */ );

_client.GetAsync(someUrl, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(gettingTask => {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    SomeStuffToDO();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

But, when operation get cancelled, `cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` throws an exception. I know that this line should to this stuff. But, in developing environment, the exception causes the visual studio to a break. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Do you mean by "visual studio to a break" that VS stops and shows the "Exception" dialog? Development or run-time, if you're not handling the exception, it'll cause your app to fail. You need to catch and handle the exception to avoid that.

Comment: @G.Stoynev Yes VS stops and shows the "Exception" dialog. So, where can I handle the exception? In the main thread or the async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle within the lambda, like this:

```
var _client = new HttpClient( /* some setthngs */ );

_client.GetAsync(someUrl, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(gettingTask => {
    try {
     cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
     SomeStuffToDO();
    }
    catch (...) { ... }
    finaly { ... }
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

But `_client.GetAsync(someUrl, cancellationToken)` might also throw cancellation exception, so you need to wrap that call (or where its containing method is awaited) with a try-catch.